Plotrange issue for multiple parametric plots inside Show command
I have following two parametric plots,
ParametricPlot[{r^2 + 1, 1/r}, {r, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.2, 0.8}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
ParametricPlot[{r^2 + 2, 2/r}, {r, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {1, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]

You can see that they have different plot ranges for y axes. individually they showing correct results. Now I want to combine these two plots to show in a single graph. So, I have used,
Show[ParametricPlot[{r^2 + 1, 1/r}, {r, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.2, 0.8}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2], 
ParametricPlot[{r^2 + 2, 2/r}, {r, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {1, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]]

But the result shows plotrange for the first plot only. How can I fix it or is there any other way to this?
Duplicate Question- Here
My question is a bit different from This. In this case a list is being formed from the same expression and PlotRange is used for single plot. So just to fix override issue PlotRange->All is used outside ListPlot in the first solution. In my case, you can see I am using two parametric plots for different functions and different plot range. Also I don't want to use PlotRange->All as I need the plots in the specified ranges only. I hope I could explain my problem correctly.

This question is similar to: Mathematica 10, Show, and PlotRange. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Domen My question  is a bit different. In the link you provided a list is being formed from the same expression and PlotRange is used for single plot. So just to fix override issue PlotRange->All is used outside ListPlot in the first solution. In my case, you can see I am using two parametric plots for different functions and different plot range. Also I don't want to use PlotRange->All as I need the plots in the specified ranges only. I hope I could explain my problem correctly.

Show will always take options from the first plot, so you either have to swap the two plots, or give PlotRange directly to Show again. How else could Show determine what you want?

@Domen That is exactly my question, if there is any other way to do so.

I gave you two options: Change the order of plots, or write Show[..., PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {1, 2}}]. What exactly do you not like about these two options? :)

@Domen In either cases Mathematica will take the plot range from 1st plot. In the first plot my range for y-axis is 0.2 to 0.8 and in second case 1 to 2. If i use Show[..., PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {1, 2}}] the first plot will also show for range 1 to 2, but in question, it is 0.2 to 0.8. I need two plots for two specified ranges. In short I need to show the first plot from 0.2 to 0.8 and the second one from 1 to 2.

It's really not clear from your description what you want. This can also be seen from the two answers below assuming two different desired outputs. Please edit your question and clarify what exactly you expect as the output (preferably make a sketch).

@Domen First answer by Bob is the one that I was looking for.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

To restrict the plots to the original plot ranges, use RegionFunction
Show[
 ParametricPlot[Tooltip@{r^2 + 1, 1/r}, {r, 1, 5},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0.2 < y < 0.8]],
 ParametricPlot[Tooltip@{r^2 + 2, 2/r}, {r, 1, 5},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2],
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 < y < 2]],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.2, 2}},
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]


EDIT: Alternatively, use ConditionalExpression and a single ParametricPlot
SolveValues[1/r == #, r][[1]] & /@ {1/5, 4/5}

(* {5, 5/4} *)

SolveValues[2/r == #, r][[1]] & /@ {1, 2}

(* {2, 1} *)

ParametricPlot[{
   {r^2 + 1, ConditionalExpression[1/r, 5/4 < r < 5]}, 
   {r^2 + 2, ConditionalExpression[2/r, 1 < r < 2]}}, 
 {r, 1, 5},
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]


